# Gamecube: Will my save work if I buy a new copy of the game?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, super-mario-sunshine

My super mario sunshine game disk has had loading issues for years, I have completed most of the game and have it saved on a memory card. If I were to buy a new game disk would my save on the memory card work on the new copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

The memory card won't care if it is the exact same copy, all it'll check for is that it is Mario Sunshine.

Comment: You should probably add that this only applies if the new copy is from the same region as the old copy. As soon as we're dealing with copies from different regions, we need to actually test compatibility to be sure.